# Using react dev tools inside iframe [In Chrome]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-redux, react-devtools

When react app is inside an iframe, dev tool chrome extension for react is not working.

Refererd: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18945

Solution suggested by the dev tools team:
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/pull/56.

"Adds the 'all_frames' option to the manifest.json to allow DevTools to access iframes that might hold the Store instead of the main page".

What should I do to enable the dev tools in iframe. should I clone the devtools repo (https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-devtools-extensions#build-steps)  and add all_frames option and use it ?

Answer (score 12):

Maybe this is too late. But, I saw this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/76#issuecomment-499888625) in some other SO conversation (which I unfortunately cannot find now)

Essentially they suggest adding this to the `body` of the `iframe`'d application.

```
<script>
    if (window.parent !== window) {
      window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = window.parent.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__;
    }
</script>
```

This seems to work for my use-case which seems similar to what the OP mentioned.

Comment: Works great. I put this in index.html of the app.

Comment: whether this works for you or not will depend on content security policy

Comment: It also requires that the parent window is a React app.

Answer (score 7):

Use this guide https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-devtools#usage-with-react-dom

1. Install react-devtools globally or locally

```
# Yarn
yarn global add react-devtools

# NPM
npm install -g react-devtools
```

2. Launch react-devtools by command in terminal: `react-devtools`

After you'll see this:
[image]

3. Put this line  to head tag in index.html/index.ejs/whatever you use and run your app
4. Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Due to CORS the other solutions did not work for me.
Instead, I utilized an external command-line (CL) tool approach. Here's how I enabled React DevTools for the iframe:

1. I added the following script to `iframe.html`:

   ```html
   <script>
     if (window.parent !== window) {
       const script = document.createElement("script");
       script.src = "http://localhost:8097";
       document.head.appendChild(script);
     }
   </script>
   ```
2. Then, I executed the command:

   ```
   npx react-devtools
   ```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks, was a big help. I had to do it in the reverse order (run the command before the page) or refresh the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a built-in extension: https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-devtools