Using React Profiler inside iframe
We have a react app that's running inside an iframe. While we don't have control over the parent app right now, we were able to use the standalone React dev tools using CLI by including this script in the head of the iframe.
<script nonce="nonce-placeholder" src="http://localhost:8097"></script>

However, this only works with the components tab. The profiler shows the following message:

We are using React 18.2.0 and trying this locally. Is there any workaround to get the Profiler working in this setup?

This setup is identical to what was suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68311408/using-react-dev-tools-inside-iframe-in-chrome
